# Como é o funcionamento básico do algoritmo A*?

Tags: algoritmo, algoritmo-de-busca, grafo, inteligência-artificial

Estou [lendo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) a respeito do algoritmo de busca A* para poder implementa-lo futuramente. Eu sei que ele é usado para encontrar um caminho em um grafo, mas não consigo visualizar muito bem como isso é feito.

Porém, estou tendo dificuldades de entender certos aspectos dele e ter uma visão simples do seu funcionamento básico. Abaixo segue algumas perguntas a respeito do funcionamento desse algoritmo.

## Perguntas

1. Como o algoritmo A* consegue encontrar caminhos em um grafo?
2. Ele é restrito a um tipo especifico de grafo?
3. Como ele determina o custo entre as arestas ligadas nos vértices do
   grafo?
4. Existe alguma formula matemática usada nesse algoritmo? Se sim,
   qual?
5. Qual tipo de estrutura de dados ele usa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Como o algoritmo A* consegue encontrar caminhos em um grafo?

O algoritmo recebe:

- o grafo
- o nodo inicial
- o nodo final
- uma função de heurística

Começando pelo nodo inicial, ele pega todos os vizinhos do nodo atual e aplica a função de heurística. Essa função retorna um número que indica qual é a distância pro nodo final (geralmente usados a distância euclidiana). O vizinho que tiver o menor valor é o mais perto do nodo final, então esse vizinho se torna o nodo atual. O mesmo procedimento é repetido até que o nodo atual seja o nodo final.

> Ele é restrito a um tipo especifico de grafo?

Não. Como expliquei acima, é preciso pegar todos os nodos vizinhos do atual. Em um grafo direcionado são todos os nodos "saindo" do atual; em um grafo não-direcionado são todos os nodos ligados ao atual.

> Como ele determina o custo entre as arestas ligadas nos vértices do grafo?

Isso é feito pela função de heurística. Essa função é muito importante, pois é ela que vai direcionar a busca pro caminho correto. Isso depende inteiramente de como o teu grafo é feito, não existe uma "regra universal" de como criar a função de heurística. Ela precisa receber por parâmetro dois nodos do grafo e retornar um número indicando quão longe esses dois nodos estão.

Por exemplo: Se o grafo representar um labirinto 2D quadrado, os índices da célula representada pelo nodo podem ser usados pra calcular a distância. A distância entre os nodos das células (1, 1) e (5, 4) pode ser calculada pela fórmula da [distância euclidiana](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dist%C3%A2ncia_euclidiana).

> Existe alguma formula matemática usada nesse algoritmo? Se sim, qual?

Isso obviamente varia de grafo pra grafo. É sua responsabilidade entender como o grafo é formado pra descobrir uma fórmula matemática pra função de heurística.

> Qual tipo de estrutura de dados ele usa?

Um grafo pode ser representado de diversas maneiras. As mais comuns são usando dois hashmaps aninhados ou com uma matriz 2D. O algoritmo A* em si geralmente é utilizado com sets e hashmaps. (Tem uma [implementação de exemplo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Pseudocode) na Wikipedia em inglês).